# How to produce a DataTable with the following result?

Tags: c#, datatable

I had retrieve two excel files from user upload using OleDb. I had produce the following result:

```
| Location | Item Type | AmountA | AmountB | Type |
|    A     |     A     |    5    |    4    |      |
```

But I want to produce the following result:

```
| Location | Item Type | AmountA | AmountB | Type |
|    A     |     A     |    5    |         |   A  |
|    A     |     A     |         |    4    |   B  |
```

These are my codes:

```
 public DataTable CombineofAdjustmentNTransaction(DataTable A, DataTable B)
    {
        DataTable TableE = new DataTable();
        TableE.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Location"));
        TableE.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Item Type"));
        TableE.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("AmountA)"));
        TableE.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("AmountB"));
        TableE.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TransactionType"));

        foreach (DataRow dtE in A.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataRow rowB in B.Rows)
            {
                if (rowB["Location"].ToString() == dtE["Location"].ToString() && rowB["Item Type"].ToString() == dtE["Item Type"].ToString() 
                    )
                {
                    var newRow = TableE.NewRow();
                    newRow["Location"] = dtE["Location"];
                    newRow["Item Type"] = dtE["Item Type"];  

                    if(dtE["Type"].ToString() == "GRN")
                    {
                        newRow["AmountA"] = dtE["AmountA"];
                        newRow["Type"] = "GRN";
                    }

                    if (rowB["Type"].ToString() == "STK_ADJ")
                    {
                        newRow["AmountB"] = rowB["AmountB"];
                        newRow["Type"] = "STK_ADJ";
                    }
                    TableE.Rows.Add(newRow);
                }
            }
        }
        return TableE;
    }
}
```

Please help thanks!

Comment: We can't tell you what you're doing wrong without seeing some example input.

Comment: "Please help thanks!" Could u please elaborate more on help

Comment: Is there any specific reason to create two rows for `A`? IMO, for the different values, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In your code you only call the `DataTable.Rows.Add()` method once. Which is why you are only getting one row.

In my solution below you will notice that I have called this method twice

```
result.Rows.Add(newRowA);
result.Rows.Add(newRowB);
```

Here is the complete refactored method for you.

```
// made these into constants, note how it reads easier when prefixing column numbers
// added benefit of renaming the columns in a single place
const string Column1Location = "Location";
const string Column2ItemType = "Item Type";
const string Column3AmountA = "Amount A";
const string Column4AmountB = "Amount B";
const string Column5TransactionType = "Transaction Type";

public DataTable CombineofAdjustmentNTransaction(DataTable tableA, DataTable tableB)
{
    DataTable result = new DataTable();
    result.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(Column1Location));
    result.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(Column2ItemType));
    result.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(Column3AmountA));
    result.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(Column4AmountB));
    result.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(Column5TransactionType));

    foreach (DataRow rowA in tableA.Rows)
    foreach (DataRow rowB in tableB.Rows)
    {
        // check for required conditions, skip if failed (continue to the next iteration)
        if (rowA["Location"] != rowB["Location"]) continue;
        if (rowA["ItemType"] != rowB["Item Type"]) continue;

        // your logic for A
        if (rowA["Type"].ToString() == "GRN")
        {
            // create row
            DataRow newRowA = result.NewRow();
            newRowA[Column1Location] = rowA["Location"];
            newRowA[Column2ItemType] = rowA["Item Type"];
            newRowA[Column3AmountA] = rowA["AmountA"];
            newRowA[Column4AmountB] = null;
            newRowA[Column5TransactionType] = "GRN";

            // add the row
            result.Rows.Add(newRowA);
        }

        // your logic for B
        if (rowB["Type"].ToString() == "STK_ADJ")
        {
            // create row
            DataRow newRowB = result.NewRow();
            newRowB[Column1Location] = rowA["Location"];
            newRowB[Column2ItemType] = rowA["Item Type"];
            newRowB[Column3AmountA] = null;
            newRowB[Column4AmountB] = rowB["AmountB"];
            newRowB[Column5TransactionType] = "STK_ADJ";

            // add the row
            result.Rows.Add(newRowB);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public DataTable CombineofAdjustmentNTransaction(DataTable A, DataTable B)
    {
        DataTable TableE = new DataTable();
        TableE.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Location"));
        TableE.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Item Type"));
        TableE.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("AmountA"));
        TableE.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("AmountB"));
        TableE.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Type"));

        foreach (DataRow dtE in A.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataRow rowB in B.Rows)
            {
                if (rowB["Location"].ToString() == dtE["Location"].ToString() && rowB["Item Type"].ToString() == dtE["Item Type"].ToString()
                    )
                {
                    var newRow = TableE.NewRow();
                    newRow["Location"] = dtE["Location"];
                    newRow["Item Type"] = dtE["Item Type"];

                    if (dtE["Type"].ToString() == "GRN")
                    {
                        newRow["AmountA"] = dtE["AmountA"];
                        newRow["Type"] = "A";
                    }

                    if (rowB["Type"].ToString() == "STK_ADJ" && newRow["AmountA"].ToString() != "" && newRow["AmountA"].ToString() != "")
                    {
                        var BNewRow = TableE.NewRow();
                        BNewRow["Location"] = rowB["Location"];
                        BNewRow["Item Type"] = rowB["Item Type"];
                        BNewRow["AmountB"] = rowB["AmountB"];
                        BNewRow["Type"] = "B";
                        TableE.Rows.Add(BNewRow);
                    }
                    else {
                        newRow["AmountB"] = rowB["AmountB"];
                        newRow["Type"] = "B";
                    }
                    TableE.Rows.Add(newRow);
                }
            }
        }
        return TableE;
    }
```